# Python multiple .txt output to many values to unpack

Tags: python, out-of-memory

I know that this problem was often handled but I still couldn't managed to get this program to work.

```
import random
filename=open('name.txt','r')
g=filename.readlines()
random.shuffle(g)
filename.close()

filename=open('lastname.txt','r')
t=filename.readlines()
random.shuffle(t)
filename.close()

for name, lastname in g, t:
        try:
                print(name + lastname + "It works")

        except:
                print 'Error00 (' + name + ')'
```

Traceback:

```
File "/python/Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    for name, lastname in f, t:
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use zip. You might like to look at izip if the size of the lists are too large for your system's memory. izip would return iterator, instead of the whole list, and you can iterate on that instead.

```
from itertools import izip 
import random

filename=open('name.txt','r') 
g=filename.readlines()
random.shuffle(g) 
filename.close()

filename=open('lastname.txt','r')
t=filename.readlines()
random.shuffle(t)
filename.close()

for name, lastname in izip(g, t):
    print(name + lastname + "It works")
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't surround your last print statement with parentheses. It's a python 3 thing.

```
print('Error00 (' + name + ')')
```

(edit)

Nevermind, you want to use zip:

```
for name, lastname in zip(g, t):
```

But you should also be consistent with your prints ;D

Comment: Thats not the problem.

Comment: Then, to quote @iCodez, what exactly is the problem? Post the traceback, please.

Comment: File "/python/Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    for name, lastname in f, t:
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random
filename=open('name.txt','r')
g=filename.readlines()
random.shuffle(g)
filename.close()

filename=open('lastname.txt','r')
t=filename.readlines()
filename.close()


for pos, name in enumerate(g):
    name = name.strip()
    lastname = random.choice(t).strip()

    print('%s %s' % (name, lastname))
```

Comment: Could you share a example from name.txt and lastname.txt? I tested here and worked fine...

Comment: Well sorry I'am an Idiot it works perfectly I opened the old file Iam so sorry -.- Thank you for your solution.